# Angular 8 + jQuery/UI problem updating view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui

I have an Angular component (Angular 8.1.3) where i use jQuery(3.4.1) and jQuery UI(1.12.1) for selecting some elements. When i have selected the elements, i would like to run a method, like the example underneath.

The problem occurs when i stop selecting, i call the method testMethod(), that adds to the loading variable and 1 second after it subtracts from the variable again + it pushes a string to the testing array.

so in the console i can see that it logs:

```
    -   first log: ('1', 1)
    -   second log: ('2', 0);
    -   third log: ('3', ['hello', 'world', 'error']);
```

It is quite as it should be :) but here is the funny part, if i outputs the same variables in the "test.component.html" 
it will not be updated, it will be:

```
    -   {{ loading }} = 0 
    -   <pre>{{ testing | json }}</pre> = ['hello', 'world']
```

The weird thing is that if I move the method call `this.testMethod();` outside of the jQuery stop function it will work like a charm.

I hope there are some of you wise people who can help here, thanks in advance :)

```js
declare const jQuery: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent {
    loading = 0;
    testing = ['hello', 'world'];

    testMethod(): void {
        this.loading++;
        console.log('1', this.loading);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.loading--;
            this.testing.push('error');
            console.log('2', this.loading);
            console.log('3', this.testing);
        }, 1000);
    }

    init(): void {
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#test')
            .selectable({
                stop: (event, ui) => {
                    this.testMethod();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try t set the testing array like this `this.testing = [ ...this.testing, 'error' ] ` . The idea here is to create new instance of the array so it will be pointing to new reference.

Comment: Hi @NikolaYankov, I tried this approach this morning, unfortunately it gives me the same result.

Comment: I think your selectable stop event does not fire, so the testMethod statements does no execute. Try a console.log() in the stop() to check if it is working.

Comment: @mehlund can you provide stackblitz/plunkr link which reproduces the issue? Meanwhile you can try to add `private cd: ChangeDetectorRef` in TestComponent constructor and call `this.cd.markForCheck();` after `console.log('3', this.testing);` in `testMethod()`.